# I have a program in that seems should work, error is down to the last line

Tags: python, syntax

I have a job interview Tuesday and they want a code sample of course. This is my first interview I was originally a chemist and I am nervous now because a cool calendar I wrote ([source code](https://gist.github.com/lcodyc4321/9160089)) isn't working.

It allows you to enter any two days called birthday and this day (I will use replace function to change 'this' to 'current') and it was giving many errors- I googled a stack-O and changed all tabs to spaces. I then deleted any spaces at the end of lines. Now the error is down to the last line?!?!

In C:\ command prompt:

```
{File: "my filename", line 386 print age_in_days(3, 29, 1955, 3, 29, 1988) 

**a cursor object points to the 's' in 'age_in_days'**

Syntax error: invalid syntax}
```

Now that I think about it again today I think I don't understand calling functions in python command prompt? I just downloaded it yesterday. But the code isn't working in Udacity's JIT interface.

Comment: Aside: you should probably simplify the code a bit.  You have variables defined you don't use (`days_in_month`) and you have a lot of repetition (long `if` chains which could be replaced by a dictionary lookup) which could be removed.  If your code works and you want comments on how to improve it, you might want to take it to [`codereview`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: to be truthful; that code you posted on github isn't going to get you a job ... and if you can't figure out a such a simple syntax error, given that Python is one of the best documented languages today, you aren't ready to have a job writing code.

Comment: God I fixed it haha, sorry disregard

Comment: Ok thank you Mr. Roberson, I just started learning a few months ago and Udacity's error did point me right to it, I tried to troubleshoot it tired at 3am. Is there a specific, good program you guys use (my friend suggested netbeans or eclipse) for python in a job setting?

Comment: And I'm reading about dictionary lookups as we speak, thanks too DSM :)

Comment: here is a hint about why you will fail that job interview immediately; about 90% of the code you wrote dealing with dates already exists in the python standard library, that is why Python is considered *batteries included*. The other 10% isn't idiomatic Python. *Working* code isn't what gets you a job, demonstrating proficiency in the language and the concepts does, and your attempt shows the opposite.

Comment: Can you give me a specific example of the lines/blocks I wrote that aren't idiomatic in python please, and what would be a better style? I take that as 'appropriate to the commonly used and good style of coding in python'

Comment: You can pretty much replace your entire program with a couple of lines if you use the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module.

Comment: That's true Tim, I just read a bit about that module. I should have been more clear on my post however, this is the first program I've written- basic as it is. It's my only code sample (first and only) and I want to improve it and display what I've learned so far, but I think people are alluding that the recruiter might not believe I actually wrote it, but that I stole the idea from a library? If so, any advice on what I should do? I've got until Tuesday and the job is barebones entry-level, I'm not sure if it'll be a big issue

Comment: I took the idea from a practice problem at Udacity, but I did the work all on my own (that's why it's so sloppy)- I didn't check anyone elses code.

Comment: And by the way, the purpose of this site is to learn or teach (at least in my interpretation). Whether or not I get my first job this week, I'm here to learn- and the course at Udacity offers a multiple video solution, which I didn't use. Hence why I wrote this program without checking the library modules, other peoples code (I know it's been done before, it's a training exercise), or the given solution in my course. If you'd like to give some useful advice that I can learn from Jarrod, I'm all ears/eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a SyntaxError in Python3 since `print` is a function.
You can use

```
print(age_in_days(3, 29, 1955, 3, 29, 1988))
```

or run your program with Python2 instead (where `print` is a statement)

Comment: thanks nibbler, when I ran it in Udacity.com where "print function(parameter)" works, and then the command prompt wouldn't take it. I'll also need to read the python site on the changes 'cause the course I use is outdated (py 2.7 I think)